# Why is 'harmful' the correct choice in this 'fill in the blank' situation?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Although gossip is not **h______** chat that can make conversations exciting, it can also be a way to spread something untrue about other people.

The above sentence is taken from a larger text on the topic of 'Netiquette' - internet manners.

The text is part of an example high-school entrance exam for Chinese students from back in 2016.

Each blank must only be filled with one word. The first letter of the word is provided to help students narrow down the number of possible word choices.

According to the answer sheet, the blank is to be filled by using the word **harmful**, which (to me) makes very little, if any, sense at all in this structure.

I have double-checked the example's punctuation and ran the [*"Although gossip is not harmful chat..."*](https://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=03htWcLGL4L-8wfP_464BQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Although%20gossip%20is%20not%20harmful%20chat%22) search string and its permutations through both Google and Bing, in the hopes of landing a hit that could confirm or refute the usage of **harmful** - all to no avail.

Below is an excerpt from the text including the sentences surrounding the problematic blank.

> The manners also **i(nclude)** not looking through others' phones and not gossiping about others over mesasges, **e(specially)** when you choose "reply all" to send a message to a group of people.
>
> Although gossip is not **h(armful)** chat that can make conversations exciting, it can also be a way to spread something untrue about other people. Gossip can be even stronger on social media than in real life, so it's **b(etter)** not to gossip.

Other than this being simply a case of [Chinglish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinglish), is there another explanation as to why the usage of **harmful** is correct here?

Comment: Only thing I could find Is an article on  [DailyMail.com](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2480723/Chatrooms-raise-risk-teenage-self-harm-Vulnerable-youths-look-empathy-help-stop-online-forums.html) about chat-rooms that raise risk of teen-age self harm.  But this doesn't jibe with "that can make conversations exciting".  So it is a mystery to me.

Comment: Thanks @ab2. That's just it. It's not only the use of 'harmful' that's boggling here. Parts of the statement, like the one you've pointed out, are self-contradictory when viewed along with the rest of the sentence. The whole thing sounds off.

Comment: If you replace "not harmful" with "harmless", the sentence does make sense. My best guess is that this is a mistranslation where someone was unaware that "not harmful" is not an appropriate synonym for innocent/harmless in this sentence. I'm quite certain it's not correct; it took me 4 read-throughs to even consider parsing the words "not harmful" as a single adjective, rather than the "not" negating the rest of the sentence.

Comment: The right word is "harmless" -- "Although gossip is not harmless chat that can make conversations exciting, ..." -- parse it as "(Although gossip) (is not) (harmless chat that can make conversations exciting,) ...". Maybe you could now google it. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris: I don't think so. The sentence is clearly juxtaposing two sides of gossip (one bad, one good). Proven by the usage of "although". Since the latter is clearly bad, the former must be good. Therefore, "Although gossip is not **harmful** chat that can make conversations exciting". I disagree with the factual correctness of that statement, but it makes the most sense when you consider the structure of the sentence.

Comment: @KernelPanic, that's a fair point you've got there. As does Flater. Both suggestions could, perhaps, benefit from one another. Flater's answer deals with the logic that makes 'harmful' a correct choice, while your tweak of parsing 'not harmful' as 'harmless' is a great alternative for outside the context and constraints of 'fill in the blank' tests.

Comment: A number of examples have surfaced here where tests were just plain wrong, and this is one of them.  IMO, @KernelPanic solved it:  it should be "harmless" -- and "not" should not be there.

Comment: @ab2 I agree that this is most likely a fluke in the test's design. However, I must give credit to Flater's answer for helping me make sense of the structure, even though we all agree that the statement in the sentence is wrong. Both KernelPanic's and Flater's input was useful to me in setting my mind at ease on this. Kernel, if you can build on Flater's explanation by adding your solution as a separate answer (or if Flater would like to edit the already existing one to include Kernel's suggestion), I'd gladly accept that.

Comment: I already upvoted the answer of @Flater.  And I have the deepest respect for people learning English as a second language --  particularly those whose first language is in an entirely different family.

Comment: @S.V.Rockwell Updated my answer, as per your request.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking why the given solution is wrong, when it's obvious to a native speaker that solution *is* wrong and the test sentence is badly designed in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> According to the answer sheet, the blank is to be filled by using the word harmful, which (to me) makes very little, if any, sense at all in this structure.

Although I disagree with the statement that is made, the structure actually makes sense.

The basic sentence structure is:

> **Although** [A], [B].

This structure juxtaposes A and B. This means that A and B *seemingly* argue opposite points.

> Although he is a thief, John is also a good man.
>   Although he is a good man, John is also a thief.

You can't definitively deduce whether A is positive and B is negative (or vice versa), but you can be sure that **one of them is positive, the other is negative**.

---

Now let's look at your example:

> **Although** [A], [B].
>
> [A] = gossip is not h______ chat that can make conversations exciting
>   [B] = it can also be a way to spread something untrue about other people

Since A is incomplete, we cannot deduce whether it's positive or negative. However, when you look at B, you see that it is clearly **negative***.

Therefore, A must be **positive**. So "not h___" must be positive, or in other words, "h___" must be negative.

"Harmful" is negative, and therefore fits the bill.

"Harmless", while more factually correct in my opinion, would cause both A and B to both be negative, and that clashes with the sentence structure of "Although [A], [B]"

---

> Although gossip is not **harmful** chat that can make conversations exciting, it can also be a way to spread something untrue about other people.

I just want to repeat here that I think the statement is completely wrong. Gossip is harmful, even when not malevolent.

But the point of the question of filling in the blank is not about filling in *your opinion*, but rather filling in *the word that fits in the sentence*.

---

*Unless it's a book written by Niccolò Machiavelli.

---

**Edit**

KernelPanic makes a good point in the comments. As per your request, adding it to my answer.

One should consider the sentence to be

> Although gossip is (not **harmful**) chat that can make conversations exciting

As opposed to

> Although gossip is not (**harmful** chat that can make conversations exciting)

The key difference is that the former example directly negates *harmful*, instead of *harmful chat that [..]*.

This seems a mistake on the part of whoever wrote the example. They are technically correct (not in meaning, but grammatically), but they did not considere that the latter example is much more likely to be understood, compared to the former.

Comment: Alright, great! +1 for looking at it as a juxtaposition. The 'Although [A],[B],' example makes the original statement somewhat easier to digest.

Comment: Since this is a Chinese test, it seems highly likely that the writer is Chinese, in which case the error is understandable. Most words for ‘harmless’ in Chinese actually do literally mean ‘not harmful’ or ‘no-harm’; 无害 _wúhài_ ‘no harm’ is perhaps the most common one. Moreover, Chinese negators _always_ precede the word they negate, so it’s unambiguous what’s negated; this is unlike English where they follow verbs but precede adjectives, leading to ambiguities like this one.

Comment: In other words, “Although gossip is (not-harmful) chat…” = 虽然闲话是**不害人**的聊天儿; vs. “Although gossip (is-not) harmful chat…” = 虽然闲话**不是**害人的聊天儿.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I wonder if the French word "ne" is an attempt to disambiguate in a way that English does not, but Chinese does (like you said). "Je suis" (I am) "Je **ne** suis **pas**" (I am not) "Je **ne** suis **plus**" (I am no longer). Many French speakers omit "ne" verbally, saying "Je suis pas" or "Je suis plus", but it is still very much present in written French. You can argue that "ne" is superfluous (as the message remains understandable when omitting "ne"), but the inherent disambiguation might explain why it is still part of official grammar.

Comment: @Flater It’s not really an attempt to disambiguate anything, no—just something that is in the process of making its exit from the language. _Ne_ is the original negator in French, meaning ‘not’; various words, mostly nouns, were added to reinforce it, like _pas_ ‘step’ or _rien_ ‘thing’: _Il ne veut pas/rien_, literally ‘he does not want a step/thing’. The original negator often tends to be lost eventually. This development is quite common (English has gone through it too) and is known as [Jespersen’s Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jespersen%27s_Cycle).

Comment: In English, the change happened long ago, before writing was common, so we neither say nor write “I ne am not”; in French, the change is still ongoing, so the formal, standard language maintains something that colloquial speech has mostly moved away from.

Comment: The parsing ' ... gossip is [not harmful chat] ...' is ungrammatical. It would have to be ' ... gossip is [non-harmful chat] ...' (dreadful) or _harmless chat_.

Answer (score 0):

> Although gossip is not h______ chat that can make conversations exciting, it can also be a way to spread something untrue about other people.

This sentence appears to suffer from an extraneous negation ('not') and the careless use of the verb to be. I think the author meant to write something like this:

*Although gossip **appears to be** harmless chat that can make conversations exciting, it can also be a way to spread something untrue about other people.*

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which is about part of an example high-school entrance exam. We can't rewrite the exam question, we can explain why the answer is what it is.

Comment: @Andrew But the answer is, as Elise points out, that the question needs rewriting.